# How to delete a row based on the data it contains?

Tags: r, for-loop, bioinformatics, delete-row

I have a table, the start is here:

```
>df
TargetID    SM_H1455_121005_4   SM_H1456_121005_1   SM_H1457_121005_7   SM_H1461_121005_2   SM_H1462_121005_8   SM_H1463_121005_1   SM_K1566_121005_6   

ENSG00000002549.7   2286    2468    2498    1696    2044    11536   4100    5460        
ENSG00000002587.5   10  0   6   2   0   2   34  
ENSG00000002726.15  8   14  0   2   16  2   4   
ENSG00000002745.8   6   2   2   0   0   4   6
```

I want to go through each row and delete every row that contains a 0. Here's my code:

```
for(i in 2:length(df)) {
df2 <- df[df[,i]!=0,]
}
```

But this code doesn't delete ALL the rows with a 0 in it. It deleted some rows but I'm not sure why and I don't think it's right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
R> foo = as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(25, 5, .25), 5, 5))
R> foo
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  3  2  3  0
2  1  1  2  2  1
3  4  2  1  1  2
4  0  0  1  1  1
5  1  2  1  1  2
R> foo[!rowSums(foo == 0),] ## or just foo[!rowSums(!foo),]
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
2  1  1  2  2  1
3  4  2  1  1  2
5  1  2  1  1  2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `any` like this:

```
ind <- apply( foo , 1 , function(x) any( x == 0 ) )
foo[ !ind , ]
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
2  2  1  1  1  2
4  2  1  1  1  4
```

Thanks to Jake for the data

Answer (score 1):

```
df[!apply(df,1,function(x) `%in%`(0,x)),]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried this but it just gave me the header? This is what it gave me: `[1] TargetID          SM_H1455_121005_4 SM_H1456_121005_1 SM_H1457_121005_7 SM_H1461_121005_2 SM_H1462_121005_8 SM_H1463_121005_1 SM_K1566_121005_6
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)`. I wanted to have a new table where there isn't a 0 anywhere in it.

Comment: Does your data have any rows that don't contain a zero? This produces the same result as Jake's answer.